# Perspective Correction Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: swift, pdf, uiimage, swift5

I am trying to add a feature in which I can import an image from Photos Library and converter it to a PDF on my app. I have everything working except for the image perspective correction using the `CIPerspectiveCorrection`.

[image]

This is what the picture originally looked like and what the cropping frame around it looks like. The frame is just a struct that holds four CGPoints. I just connect them with lines. The box is movable. It looks like this ...

`Rectangle(topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint)`

After I call a CIPerspectiveCorrection function that I created ...

`extension UIImage {
func flattened(rect: Rectangle) -> UIImage? {
let ciImage = CIImage(image: self)!

```
    guard let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2) else { return nil }
    let ciContext =  CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext)

    let perspectiveCorrection = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")!
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: rect.topLeft), 
                                    forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: rect.topRight),
                                    forKey: "inputTopRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: rect.bottomRight),
                                       forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint :rect.bottomLeft),
                                       forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(ciImage,
                                       forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    if let output = perspectiveCorrection.outputImage,
        let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }

    return nil
}`
```

I call it here ...

`imageView.image = (imageScrollView.subviews[page] as! UIImageView).image?.flattened(rect: rects[page].scale(scaleBy: (imageScrollView.subviews[page] as! UIImageView).image!.size.width / view.frame.width))`

`page` is simply which page of the scroll view the user is on. There can be multiple images.

The end result is as follows.

[image]

I ran a function that automatically gets the right Perspective Correction, but I want the user to be able do it themselves. I added this code and it works beautifully, but I still want the user interaction aspect. It also has the added benefit of showing what a good result looks like and the printed output.

let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle,
context: ciContext,
options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])!

```
    guard let autoRect = detector.features(in: ciImage).first as? CIRectangleFeature
            else { return nil }
```

These are the print statements...

```
print("Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: \(rect.topLeft), topRight: \(rect.topRight), bottomRight: \(rect.bottomRight), bottomLeft: \(rect.bottomLeft))")
print("Automatic Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: \(autoRect.bottomLeft), topRight: \(autoRect.bottomRight), bottomRight: \(autoRect.topRight), bottomLeft: \(autoRect.topLeft)")
```

These are the outputs...

> Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: (460.10, 549.45), topRight: (2513.56,
> 600.58), bottomRight: (2834.95, 3465.077957028928), bottomLeft: (255.58, 3549.07))
>
> Automatic Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: (568.21,
> 2570.43), topRight: (568.21, 2570.43), bottomRight: (3567.015, 183.82), bottomLeft: (514.13, 420.42)

I have no idea why this is happening and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think core image’s origin is in the bottom left, so you might need to convert (subtract origin from height of screen, then add image height)

Comment: You're not taking account of the difference between the image as you are shown it and the real image which you are applying Core Image to.

Comment: I agree with @aheze - while UIKit (UIImage) and CGImage have an origin of the **top** left, CIImage has an origin of the **bottom** left. I used to have a simply function to flip the Y axis to do this, but lost it over the years. That may not be the complete issue - it should be (I think) flipped upside down, not mirrored like your output - but try working with your input vectors... they may be correct, just applied as wrong input. The X coordinates should be as computed. But the Y coordinates need to reflect the 0,0 is the bottom left, not top left.

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys. When I reverse all of the points. topLeft to bottomLeft for example. It has the same output just reversed. What I did was add a line that gets the edges automatically, I still want the user to have control of exactly whats cropped. I printed their corners... Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: (460.10, 549.45), topRight: (2513.56, 600.58), bottomRight: (2834.95, 3465.077957028928), bottomLeft: (255.58, 3549.07)) ---
Automatic Rectangle Bounds: (topLeft: (568.21, 2570.43), topRight: (568.21, 2570.43), bottomRight: (3567.015, 183.82), bottomLeft: (514.13, 420.42)